# create a simple pdf report from html

Tags: reporting, pdf-generation, html-rendering

I'm looking for a way to generate pdf files from html

In order to make simple tabular reports I would need the following features

- table rendering
- variable page size
- repeating headers / footers on every page
- calculated page number / total page
- css support would be nice

I know there have been many similar questions in stackoverflow, but I don't know if there's a product that supports the aforementioned features...

Ideally, the source would be a plain and simple well built html with css, (I'm building the html files, so I can adapt to the products needs, that is, it won't have to render every piece of html crap you can throw at a browser) and with some custom tags to configure headings, footer, page size, etc...

then I would run a command line to convert it from html to pdf.

I think http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/ does something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)

Check out the [examples](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples).